# Прямоугольная сетка

Tags: c++

Задача следующая: даны произвольные четыре точки в декартовой системе координат и они образуют выпуклый четырехугольник. Необходимо вывести все точки, которые образованы прямоугольной сеткой, натянутую на этот образованный четырехугольник. Сложность в том, что тип, используемый для создания сетки double(вещественное число двойной точности).

Проблемы:

1. Вывести все не повторяющиеся точки сетки, разумно распределить их внутренние и внешние точки(внутренние - то, что внутри четырехугольника, внешние - лежат на границе).
2. Нужно учесть что внешние точки могут быть образованы уравнением y=2 или x=5.
3. Нужно учесть, что два цикла не дают всех точек. Нужно учесть, все эти 4 точки.
4. Возникает проблема, когда шаг очень большой, могут возникать аномалия - в том, что линии образованные x и y не пересекаются, но они внешние.

Помогите пожалуйста, листингом программы!

Причем шаг любой! Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли понял, но я думаю, самая левая точка это будет первый (нулевой) столбец, отсчитываете по одной точке до самой крайней правой, это последний столбец, то же самое с верхом и низом, вот прямоугольная сетка и готова, дальше два цикла чтобы их вывести.